# Finding a volume of a region bounded by y=1/x

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Let $S$ be region enclosed by $y= 1/x$, $y=1$ and $y=2$. Goal is to find the volume of $S$ when it is revolved about $x= -1$

#### try:

Best to use washer method wrt y coordinate. A volume element is

$$ dV = ( \pi (1 + 1/y)^2 - \pi (-1)^2 ) dy $$ Thus,

$$ V = \int_1^2 (1 + 2/y + 1/y^2 - 1 ) dy = \int_1^2 (2/y + 1/y^2) dy $$

is this a correct setting for the required volume?

Comment: Also, in the integral, $(1+\frac {2}{y}+\frac {1}{y^2}-1) = (\frac {2}{y}+\frac {1}{y^2}) \neq (\frac {2}{y}-\frac {1}{y^2})$

Comment: It is not a bounded region unless you include the line $x=0$

Comment: yes, line x=0 is also included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shaded area below is the region $S$.
[image]

Let us write $f(y)=\frac{1}{y}$. The outer radius is $f(y)+1$ and the inner radius is $1$. Thus, by using the washer method, $$dV=\pi\bigg(\big[f(y)+1\big]^2-1^2\bigg)dy$$ so that the volume is given by
$$V=\int_{1}^2 dV=\int_{1}^2\pi\bigg(\big[f(y)+1\big]^2-1^2\bigg)dy=\pi\int_1^2 \left(\frac{2}{y} + \frac{1}{y^2}\right) dy.$$ Your only mistake is you introduced $(-1)^2$ and that you don't have $\pi$ in your integral.